# Back Button with keeping form value

Tags: javascript, php, forms, back

Here is how the back button :

```
<button onclick="history.go(-1);">Back </button>
```

(this button is called outside the form, otherwise it doesn't work, I don't know why ...)

**The Situation**

I have 4 pages like this :

```
Page 1 : Form for information level 1
Page 2 : Form for information level 2
Page 3 : Summary of the 2 precedent Form
Page 4 : Form post succes page
```

I have put the BACK button on page 2 and 3.
For the Page 2, it works perfectly. When I click on, I get all my previous value back.

**My problem**

It comes from the BACK button of the Page 3.
All my form values are gone ...

Soo, I know I can do it by including the BACK button in the form and then POST again all my value to the previous page but I was wondering if there isn't an "easy and quicker" way to do that ?

Thanks.

Comment: use session and make page refresh on back and show values of input back from session

Comment: You could store the values in a session. This way the data is not lost.

Comment: You mean, after each POST, I save the $_POST -> $_SESSION. Then when I show the form, I do something like "if (isset($_SESSION))" put that value otherwise nothing? If its that, itsn't it the same way than re-sending the $_POST to the previous page ... ?

Comment: Actually, I just wanna know if I can do this without saving all the $_POST somewhere ?

Comment: how about using some jquery and html and css and use the same page to show all three forms by hidding divs instead off going back into history you can just hide/show divs when the user clicks back / next

Comment: Thats an option but now its kinda too late to change all my page structure ... and you ain't answering to my question :p

Comment: For button to be "button" and not "submit button", you MUST specify type `<button type="button"></button>`

Comment: You see the old data because your browser has autocomplete enabled, not because of some magic PHP/HTML property

Comment: ok, soo I can't do without saving them or re-send them ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) For button not to submit form, you have to specify it's type: `<button type="button"></button>`

2) Your problem can be solved few ways:

a) Save all values on clicking `Next` to session and when returning to page, just save all values.
Your inputs than will look something like
`<input type='text' value='<?php echo isset($_SESSION['a1']) ? $_SESSION['a1'] : ''; ?>' name='a1'/>`;
In PHP side: `$_SESSION['a1'] = isset($_POST['a1']) ? $_POST['a1'] : '';`.
In last confirmation step you save values from last form + values from session to database and clear your session.

b) You can use single form with tabs in it and only show specific tab with jQuery/js:

```
<div class='tab' data-ref='#tab1'>First step tab</div>
<div class='tabContent' id='tab1'>Content of first step tab</div>

$('.tab').click(function(){
    $('.tabContent').hide();
    $($(this).data('ref')).show();
});
```

And only save all data at last step.
I personally would take `b` variant

Comment: Thanks for taking time and explaining me, and I went for the option B but only with php :D